Correct Latin Translation of "Problem Solver"
I have searched high and low for the best way to translate "Problem Solver". Obviously the first thing that is suggested is "quaestio solver" but I feel that might be incorrect. I also noticed that "quaestio" seemed to be specifically referring to math problems. Was looking to reference problems of life, if that matters in the translation. Can someone maybe help with this? Thank you for your time and consideration.
-V
